# Angular 4 - fetching data from Service and storing in Component

Tags: angular

I have Services set up in Angular to fetch JSON data from REST webservices. Now I consume data from service in `OnInit` method and store in local made array. But when I access them it shows `undefined`. Services are working fine, checked that data is coming or not. Sorry for bad english, not native language.

```
constructor(private myService: MyService, private anotherService: AnotherService) {}

arr: any[];
arr2: any[];

ngOnInit() {
 this.myservice.getData(12).subscribe((data) => {
  this.arr = data;
 });
 for (let item of this.arr) {
  if (item.id == 5) {
   this.arr2.push(item);
  }
 }
 console.log('Data - ', this.arr2); // --> This shows undefined :(
}
```

But this works when I call custom method from `OnInit`

```
constructor(private myService: MyService, private anotherService: AnotherService) {}

arr: any[];
arr2: any[];

ngOnInit() {
 this.myservice.getData(12).subscribe((data) => {
  this.arr = data;
  this.stage();
 });
}

stage() {
for (let item of this.arr) {
  if (item.id == 5) {
   this.arr2.push(item);
  }
 }
 console.log('Data - ', this.arr2); // --> This shows data :)
}
```

Someone help understand why. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good old asynchronous call issue.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.myservice.getData(12).subscribe(...);
 for (let item of this.arr) {...}
 console.log(...);
}
```

First line, you request data with an asynchronous call. Basically, put into words :

> Go fetch data, and when you have it, do what I tell you to do in the `subscribe.`

Once this order is given, the code continues to be run.

This means that if your call takes 10 seconds to complete, Angluar won't wait 10 seconds before launching your `for` loop : **it will run instantly**.

That's why you don't see your data. It is outside of the subscribe function.

Comment: If I use `AfterContentInit` will it resolve issue or have to put rest code inside `subscribe` ?

Comment: You need to put your code into a function that will be launched in your subscribe, just like you did when you made it work.

Comment: `AfterContentInit` is a lifecycle hook, it has nothing to do with HTTP calls.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the code from outside the `.subscribe()` inside of it. The code inside the `.subscribe()` is asynchronous meaning the code below it gets executed straight away rather than waiting for the code inside the `.subscribe()` to complete.